# Highlight word on html page if word is defined in a database

Tags: dictionary, signals, words, multimedia

We are developing a multimedia dictionary system.  The idea is that, if you're on a webpage, and there's a word you don't know, you double-click on a word and a dictionary pops up.

The dictionary differs from [google's dictionary for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-dictionary-by-goog/mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja?hl=en), in that is contains multimedia, is multilingual, and it contains supplemental info beyond the mere meaning of the word.

Our problem is this: we can't possibly define all the words on every page in the web in our database.  That means that many words on a page might not be defined.  Rather than having users double-click a word to see if there's a definition, we want to check against our database which words on the page are defined as the page is loading.  We then want to highlight the defined words on the webpage, so readers can see which words are defined.

We've got the pop-up mostly working the way we want it.  The challenge is that it has to work on webpages where we aren't the page owners (such as when we develop our system as a browser extension), meaning we can't do

`<span class="dict">consetetur</span>`

Here's what we've done so far - only works in Chrome: [gwizz demo page](https://eped.tut.ac.za/gwizz/page.html).  Click through the security, the server is not yet secure.

On our page, most of the words are defined, so you can double-click any word, and it will display the pop-up.  On most pages, however, there will be many words not defined in the database.  Readers will eventually get frustrated if they click on too many words with no definition in the database.  That's what we want to avoid by signalling the words which **are** defined.

In my mind, that would require starting at the top of the page, and testing every word against the database, and if it is defined, to hgihlight the word in another colour, for example, and then testing the next word.  That sounds to me as if it will be a fairly slow process.  I was wondering if there would be a faster way?

Answer (score 0):

You should use AJAX for this, it's pretty simple

So that you wrap any word in a tag like that

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <span class="dict">consetetur</span> sadipscing elitr.
```

For easier AJAX you can use jQuery, it's the most used library for this, so it would look like:

```
$('span.dict').bind('click', function() {
    $.ajax("lookup.php", {
        data: {word: $(this).text()}, // the word 'consetetur' in this example
        success: function(data) {
           /* show your popup - data contains here the content of lookup.php
             you can use something like bootstrap modals or sweetalert for this

           */
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert('Error:\n' + JSON.stringify(error));
            // always handle your ajax errors!
        }
    });
});
```

And your `lookup.php` should be very simple too:

```
<?php

/* setup the database connection*/
$word = $_POST['word'];
$result = $db->query("SELECT text FROM dict WHERE word = '$word' );
echo $result;
```

Remember, this is example code! Not safe, not tested. But it shows how to solve your problem :)

Comment: Thanx, so far!

I added some moe info into my original question.  Our current issue isn't to get the pop-up working, but to signal the words on a page for which a definition exists in the database

G

Comment: You should check if the content is loaded and then stop requesting the word over and over again - if somebody selects some text on this page and leaves the page open for 10minutes the users browser loads continuously request from the server